# Unable to set dynamic validation for fields using angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm facing an issue with an existing application, below is my scenario
I'm having the below JSON format

.html code

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div *ngFor="let property of Tree.properties">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#dataCatg-{{property.name}}">
              <div *ngIf="property.required">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>{{property.name}}
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="!property.required">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>{{property.name}}
              </div>
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="dataCatg-{{property.name}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let prop of property.details">
                <div *ngIf="prop.details.visible">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div *ngIf="data.includes(prop.name)">
                        <label class="inline-label" for="{{prop.name}}">{{prop.name}}</label>
                      </div>
                      <div *ngIf="!data.includes(prop.name) ">
                        <label class="inline-label " for="{{prop.name}} ">{{prop.name}}</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8 ">
                      <div *ngIf="!Edit">
                        <span *ngIf="formVisible && metaDataTemplateMap[selectedFile]!==undefined ">
                          <input id="{{prop.name}}" type="{{prop.details.type}} " [(ngModel)]="Data[prop.name]" class="form-control ">
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <div *ngIf="Edit">
                        <div *ngIf="prop.details.group ">
                          <span *ngIf="formView">
                            <!--need-->
                            <input id="{{prop.name}}" type="{{prop.details.type}}" [(ngModel)]="Edit[prop.name]" (ngModelChange)="Edit($event)" style=" border-radius:0;"
                             class="form-control">
                          </span>
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="!prop.details.group ">
                          <input id="{{prop.name}}" type="text " style=" border-radius:0" class="form-control " readonly>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

.ts Code

```
Data(res) {


    this.Tree['Properties'] = [];

    for (let property in res.properties) {

      var prop = res.properties[property];
      if (prop['properties'] !== undefined) {
        let temp= {};
        if (res['required'].indexOf(property) !== -1) {
          temp['required'] = true;
        }
        else {
          temp['required'] = false;
        }
        temp['name'] = property;
        let template = {};
        temp['details'] = [];
        for (let nestedProps in prop.properties) {
          let nestedProp = {};
          nestedProp['name'] = nestedProps;

          if (prop.properties[nestedProps]['type'] == 'string' || prop.properties[nestedProps]['type'] == 'date-time') {
            prop.properties[nestedProps]['type'] = 'text';
            template[nestedProps] = '';
          }

          if (prop.properties[nestedProps]['type'] == 'integer') {
            prop.properties[nestedProps]['type'] = 'number';
            template[nestedProps] = 0;
          }

          if (prop.properties[nestedProps]['type'] == 'array') {
            prop.properties[nestedProps]['type'] = 'array';
            template[nestedProps] = '';
          }
          if (prop.properties[nestedProps]['group'] == true) {
            if (this.Edit[property] == undefined)
              this.Edit[property] = {};
            this.Edit[property][nestedProps] = '';
          }

          nestedProp['details'] = prop.properties[nestedProps];

          temp['details'].push(nestedProp);
        }
        this.Data[property] = template;
        this.Tree['Properties'].push(temp);
      }
      if (prop['properties'] == undefined) {
        let temp = {};
        if (res['required'].indexOf(property) !== -1) {
          temp['required'] = true;
        }
        else {
          temp['required'] = false;
        }
        temp['name'] = property;
        if (prop['type'] == 'string' || prop['type'] == 'date-time') {
          prop['type'] = 'text';
          this.Data[property] = '';
        }

        if (prop['type'] == 'number') {
          prop['type'] = 'integer';
          this.Data[property] = 0;
        }

        if (prop['group'] == true) {
          this.Edit[property] = '';
        }
        temp['details'] = prop;
        this.Tree['Others'].push(temp);
      }
    }


  }
```

here what I'm want is 1. if You see in the JSON I have

```
"required": [
    "host", 
    "quantity", 
    "id"
],
```

while generating the fields it has to check the above mentioned fields are empty or not with out template or reactive form approach how can it be possible if the fields are empty then we have let user know that fields are empty how can I accomplish this ?

Comment: is there a particular reason why you don't want to use reactive forms? Also what do you mean by "let user know that fields are empty" do you want to display something?

Comment: Would you please give an example or dummy data of your json `Tree` and `Edit`. or create running example on `stackblitz`.

Comment: @YoukouleleY this is an existing application which already developed with out that if i want to build that in reactive forms then it may take some time and i wan t to display an alert if the give fields in array are empty

Comment: @Nour i will update it shortly..

Comment: I would say that this is in dire need of a refactor, and that you should convert it to reactive forms to save yourself inevitable future pain!

Comment: ok
it is really required to give [(ngModel)]="instance.quantity" bcoz my ngmodel by default contains <input #dt id="{{property.name}} " type="{{property.details.type}} " [(ngModel)]="DataTemplateMap[selectedFile][property.name] " 
required style=" border-radius:0" class="form-control ">
i already have a ngmodel so u mentioned that it is required to give ngmodel so i cannot give 2 ngModels

Comment: I have answered this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52981337/required-suggestion-related-to-generating-dynamic-forms-using-angular/52988434#comment92882966_52988434 , as I am assuming both question json is same, but that is in a reactive form, do you need the same thing in template driven form?

Comment: @AjayOjha no what sunil singh solution is optimal at present and in future can convert it in to reactive or template form

Comment: In your Html-code you call Tree.properties, and is the ts-code u use Tree["Properties"] (p -> P). Is this a typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ### Aim

Validation of dynamic generated form input without `Reactive` or `Template` Approach.

> ### Solution

`Directive` will be best use for such kind of requirement. `Directive` helps to break the complicated job into small independent task. Lets see how it can be implemented.

***Implementation provided below doesn't require any change in your existing code.***

### 1. Validate Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ValidateService {

  errors = {};

  validate(key: string, value: object) {
    this.errors[key] = value;
  }

  getErrors() {
    let errorList = [];
    Object.keys(this.errors).forEach(key => {
      let value = this.errors[key];
      if ((value == undefined || value == '')  && this.required.find(item=>item == key)) {
        errorList.push({ name: key, error: key + " Field is required" })
      }
    });
    return errorList;
  }

   //All required fields can be maintained here
  required = [
    "host",
    "quantity",
    "id"
  ]

}
```

### 2. Validate Directive

`ValidateDirective` is responsible to collect the current value of `input` control if any change happens. This information will be passed to the service class `ValidationService`.

```
import { Directive, Host, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, ViewContainerRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ValidateService } from './validate.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[validate]'
})
export class ValidateDirective implements OnChanges {

  constructor(private service: ValidateService, private containerRef: ViewContainerRef) {

  }

  @Input("ngModel") model;

  @Input("validate") element;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.service.validate(this.containerRef.element.nativeElement.id, changes.model.currentValue);
    })
  }

}
```

### 3. Directive Usage

`ValidateDirective` can be used with any input controls which has `id` and `ngModel`.

ex:

```
<input [validate] id="{{prop.name}}" type="{{prop.details.type}}" [(ngModel)]="Edit[prop.name]" (ngModelChange)="Edit($event)" style=" border-radius:0;" class="form-control">
```

### 4. Component ts

`ValidateService` will be Injected into component to get the list of errors.

```
constructor(private service:ValidateService) {}

  public get errors(){
    return this.service.getErrors();
  }
```

### 5. Displaying errors

Since all errors are available in Component, it can be displayed in the html.

ex :

```
 <li *ngFor="let error of errors">
     {{error.error}}
 </li>
```

> Note - There are many thing which can be enhanced further like
>
> > 1. Passing custom message to `Directive`.
> > 2. `Required field list` can be passed to Directive as @Input

Working sample demo is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnbzqd

Comment: ok but in the service.ts u have maintained the required fields in static way but i am getting those via json schema  & how to can display these dynamic fields name in alert i mean what ever required fields is not empty can i show it in alert

Comment: Since this in service class, we can create the setter for the required list and this can be set from the Component or any other class. I have updated the demo as well.

Comment: i mean i have a dropdown and based on the the value the various json schema's are being loaded so in that case also it is possible ?

Comment: yes, you just need to pass it to service class. that's all.

Comment: ok and how can i get the field name so that i can show that in alert suppose  at first user doest fill 3 mandatory fields  they user will get alert too as these fields are not filled after user out of 3 fields user enter 2 fields and 1 fields left and again it will show alert that particular field is not filled

Comment: You can pass the name into control ex `<input id="host" name="Host" type="text"  [validate] [(ngModel)]="instance.host"/>`. I have updated the `ValidationService` class. Now it hold the value, id and name of each individual control.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182670/discussion-between-madpop-and-sunil-singh).

Comment: can we just make the logic  which is in ngonchanges in to a button click ?

Comment: `ngonchanges ` collect the control details so that is needs to be there however if you want to control when the error should be displayed then you can play with `ValidationService`.