# Required suggestion related to generating dynamic forms using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here i am facing a conflict i have a requirement where by using a complex json i need to develop a multiple fields and that fields also will be displayed based on multiple if condition & the validation also to be done only to certain fields so here i just want to know to this kind of scenario which approach is better

1. Reactive Approach or 2. Not following the angular approach and following a normal dynamic fields creation

sample Json:

```
{
    "name": "hugo", 
    "type": "object", 
    "required": [
        "host", 
        "quantity", 
        "id"
    ], 
    "info": {
        "host": {
            "editable": false, 
            "visible": true, 
            "type": "string", 
            "group": true
        }, 
        "information": {
            "type": "object", 
            "properties": {
                "filetype": {
                    "visible": true, 
                    "search": "date", 
                    "editable": true, 
                    "type": "string", 
                    "group": true
                }, 
                "id": {
                    "visible": true, 
                    "type": "string", 
                    "editable": true, 
                    "group": false
                }, 
                "size": {
                    "visible": true, 
                    "type": "integer", 
                    "editable": true, 
                    "group": false
                }, 
                "filename": {
                    "visible": true, 
                    "type": "string", 
                    "editable": true, 
                    "group": false
                }

          }
        }, 
        "picture": {

            "type": "object", 
            "properties": {
                "hash": {
                    "search": "yes", 
                    "group": true, 
                    "editable": false, 
                    "visible": true, 
                    "type": "string"
                }, 
                "url": {
                    "search": "yes", 
                    "group": false, 
                    "editable": true, 
                    "visible": true, 
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }, 

        "quantity": {
            "editable": true, 
            "visible": true, 
            "type": "string", 
            "group": true
        }, 

        "id": {
            "group": false, 
            "editable": true, 
            "visible": true, 
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

here i have to structure the form like below

```
information   -> this is name & below are the fields
   --filetype  
   --id
```

what ever under information,picture & host ,quantity has to be created as fields say like form groups

Comment: can you explain it JSON or code snippet?

Comment: it can be possible with reactive form approach in angular. but can you please provide JSON schema with validation rules.

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth sample json updated

Comment: @AjayOjha  sample json updated here what ever names i mentioned in "required": [
        "host", 
        "quantity", 
        "id"
    ],   they should not be empty and other fields can be empty

Comment: is mentioned properties are fixed or those are also dynamic?

Comment: @AjayOjha    it is a dynamic json thing may increase or decrease

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268923/form-validation-for-dynamic-table-tr-angular-5/52269145#52269145 you can refer this

Comment: Ok, Thanks, I will update you after some time with working sample.

Comment: @AjayOjha ok thank you